# What's the easiest way to extract part of this line?

Tags: powershell

I am using PowerShell to insert data into a database but before I get to that step I need to pull the information from a log file. How can I extract the title of the project from this line in the log file?

```
1>Project "E:\Builds\1\IS_WSD\Lab1\src\Lab1.sln" on node 1 (default targets).
```

The title would be "Lab1.sln"

I already have `(Get-Content C:\Users\myusername\Documents\Lab1.log)[1]` which pulls this whole line but I need to narrow down even more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this:

```psh
$logfile = 'C:\Users\myusername\Documents\Lab1.log'
(Get-Content $logfile)[1] -replace '^.*?".*?\\([^\\]+)".*', '$1'
```

or this:

```psh
$logfile = 'C:\Users\myusername\Documents\Lab1.log'
(Get-Content $logfile)[1] -replace '^.*?"' -replace '".*$' -replace '^.*\\'
```

Comment: I am actually just looking for the last part of the path with Lab1.sln

Answer (score 3):

How about a regex way:

```
$x = '1>Project "E:\Builds\1\IS_WSD\Lab1\src\Lab1.sln" on node 1 (default targets).'
$x -match '".*\\(.*)"'
$Matches[1]
```

or a not regex way:

```
$x.SubString($x.LastIndexOf('\')+1, ($x.LastIndexOf('"')-$x.LastIndexOf('\'))-1)
```